# Comparação de retorno de query com status "N"

Tags: c#, if, sintaxe

Preciso de ajuda para comparação no "if" c# de um retorno de banco de dados dataTable.

Abaixo o trecho do código:

```
public class ArcerarDto
{
    public DataTable SelectArcerarContract()
    {
        ArcerarDal arcerarObj = new ArcerarDal();
        DataTable arcerarDt = arcerarObj.SelectArcerar();


        if (arcerarDt.Rows[0][2].ToString() = 'N') ///// erro aqui
        {
            //logFile "ERRO", "Contrato do xxx está Inativo."
            //aborta processamento
        }
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Bom não sei ainda se é a melhor forma de comparar mais um sinal de igual é atribuição e dois sinal de igual juntos é comparação, então o seu código pode ser somente erro de digitação.

Comment: obrigada Virgilio!

Comment: Nem pode comparar string com char faça...  `== "N"`

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda! Deu certo

Answer (score 2):

```
if (arcerarDt.Rows[0][2].ToString() = 'N')// erro
```

Operador de igualdade em C#: ==.
A utilização do "=" é quando você vai setar algum valor a variável ou propriedade.
No caso de IF / ELSE utiliza-se operando "==" (operador de igualdade).

```
if (arcerarDt.Rows[0][2].ToString() == "N")// correto
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificar se não faltou um `"="` no trecho abaixo:

```
if (arcerarDt.Rows[0][2].ToString() **==** 'N')
```